# latexdiff produces non-compilable file in presence of \lstMakeShortInline

Tags: listings, latexdiff

I'm using `latexdiff` on a file that uses the `listings` package, and more specifically its `lstMakeShortInline` macro, that allows writing inline code in a concise way. If I start with the following `orig.tex` file:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\tt}
\lstMakeShortInline"
\begin{document}
Test short inline: "this is a listing"
\end{document}
```

and want to make a diff with `new.tex` (containing a new line with an inline listing in short form):

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\tt}
\lstMakeShortInline"
\begin{document}
Test short inline: "this is a listing"
Test short inline: "this is another listing"
\end{document}
```

then `latexdiff orig.tex new.tex | pdflatex -jobname=diff` will report an error:

```
*! Argument of \lst@temp has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*>  }
      \DIFaddend\end{document}
?
```

This is not the case if I use `\lstinline` instead of the shortcut `"`, hence a crude workaround is to use a filter of the form `sed -e 's/"\([^"]*\)"/\\lstinline"\1"/g'`, but this seems a bit fragile (even though it did the trick on my real use case). Is there a better alternative?